# How to properly cleanup Node.js abnormal exit/termination process

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am wondering, what is the best implementation to handle Node.js abnormal process termination. I am currently using [ESLint Plugin Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-node) recommended rule which recommends disabling the usage of `process.exit()` [here](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-process-exit.md).
The NodeJS documentation about [process exit code](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) also states that manually calling `process.exit()` explicitly is bad. Instead, use `process.exitCode` to tell the process which exit code to use when the process exits gracefully.

However, this is how I currently handle the problems (Based on others question asked in Stackoverflow):

```
// List of abnormal signal
const termination = ['SIGINT', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGUSR2', 'uncaughtException', 'SIGTERM'];

// Redirect abnormal signal listener to process.exit()
termination.forEach((signal) => process.on(signal, (exitCode) => process.exit(exitCode))); // eslint-disable-line no-process-exit

// Handle process termination cleanup inside Exit event listener (Can be more than 1 listener across codebase)
process.on('exit', (signal) => {
  // Perform any synchronous operations to cleanup process before termination (Ex: Close database connection)

  console.info(`Recieved Signal (${signal})`);
});
```

In the above piece of code, I disabled the ESLint `no-process-exit` rule explicitly for this case, because from what I read in the NodeJS documentation about [Signal Event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) if some these signals have a listener installed, we need to manually exit the Node application.
Is there any recommendation to handle Node.js process clean up better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [node-cleanup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cleanup). It's a nice package that provides an easy way of cleaning up resources before the node process exits.

```js
const nodeCleanup = require('node-cleanup');
 
nodeCleanup((exitCode, signal) => {
    // release resources here before node exits
});
```

Comment: Hello Duc, I've downvoted this answer because node-cleanup has not been updated in six years.

Comment: Hmm that's sad. If you find an alternative, please share with us here. Thank you!